# looping .load jquery setting rel

Tags: jquery

```
var resultValue = $("#"+temp+" .panId").val();
for(var i=0; i<totalPanel;i++) {
    $("#"+temp+" .panelDiv").append('<div class="panelDiv' + resultValue + '"></div>');
    $("#"+temp+" .panelDiv" +resultValue ).load("Panel.html #w", function(){
        $(".panelDiv"+(resultValue-1)+" .txtWidth").attr('rel',resultValue-1);
        $(".panelDiv"+(resultValue-1)+" .txtHeight").attr('rel',resultValue-1);
        $(".panelDiv"+(resultValue-1)+" .btnRemovePanel").attr('rel',resultValue-1);
    });
    resultValue++;
    $("#"+temp+" .panId").val(resultValue);
}
```

Basically i trying to trigger a load function. after the load function is trigger i want to set a rel <- into each so if my for loop loop 5 time rel will be 1 2 3 4 5
but now it is being set as 5 5 5 5 5 because .loop callbackfunction only execute after the loop is complete then it is being load.therefore my value resultValue is at the max of the value.
how can i solve by setting rel 1 2 3 4 5.

Comment: why are you using 'resultValue', when you've got that nice `i` variable that'll be autoincrementing already?

Comment: resultValue can start from 10

Comment: And speaking of which, what is resultValue? Where is it set? What is it supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found an alternative

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("body").on('change','.txtTotalHeight',function(){
  for(var i=0; i<totalPanel;i++) {
     test();

  }
 }
}
function test(){
var resultValue = $("#"+temp+" .panId").val();

    $("#"+temp+" .panelDiv").append('<div class="panelDiv' + resultValue + '"></div>');
    $("#"+temp+" .panelDiv" +resultValue ).load("Panel.html #w", function(){
        $(".panelDiv"+(resultValue-1)+" .txtWidth").attr('rel',resultValue-1);
        $(".panelDiv"+(resultValue-1)+" .txtHeight").attr('rel',resultValue-1);
        $(".panelDiv"+(resultValue-1)+" .btnRemovePanel").attr('rel',resultValue-1);
    });
    resultValue++;
    $("#"+temp+" .panId").val(resultValue);
}
```